# casting unique_ptr to char** to pass it as an function argument Func(char** arg)

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

With c style `char` I would have:

```
void FunctionCannotBeChanged(char** pVar)
{
    ... do something/modify the content of the buffer
}

int main(..)
{
    char* buffer = NULL;
    Func(&buffer)
}
```

If I want to to have a buffer as a `unique_ptr`

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer;
buffer = std::make_unique<char[]>(bufferSize);
```

What would be the correct way to pass the new buffer to `FunctionCannotBeChanged` by reference?

Comment: There isn't one. Your function might do things that are incompatible with `std::unique_ptr`. You need to find out what `FunctionCannotBeChanged` is allowed to do. How exactly can it modify `*pvar`?

Comment: That double-pointer is what makes it very difficult. That indicates that the function could reallocate the data and reassign the original pointer. This will not be possible with a smart pointer. If you have data in another object, then you need to copy the data into a new (temporary) buffer, pass a pointer to that (temporary) buffer pointer, and then either copy the data back or create a new smart pointer or other string-like object (and I really recommend you use `std::string` for any string-like data, or possible `std::vector`, instead of smart pointers).

Comment: The real message is: avoid `function(char**)` and libraries that use it if you can. Still, take all things in consideration and if needed, do as described in the previous comment. Also, prefer `std::string` and `std::vector<unsigned char>` over `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>`.

Comment: Do you know if the function reallocates the buffer? If so, do you know what it uses for the reallocation? Is it `std::malloc` or `new[]`?

Comment: yes, the function reallocates the buffer. It is a library which is a black box for me. So I do not know what it does. I corrected the example.

Comment: @branero79 Does the library documentation tell you how the memory is reallocated?

Comment: @branero79 If the library allocates the memory, how is it freed? Is there an additional function for this?

Comment: We would need to see either the documention for `FunctionCannotBeChanged` or its code. Otherwise, there is no way we could possibly know how to call it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

First of all the shown function requires the buffer to be of type `char*` but your buffer is of the type `unsigned char*`, the types have to match.

> the function reallocates the buffer

If it reallocates the buffer, then it owns the buffer as soon as you pass it to the function, and due to that your `unique_ptr` must not own that buffer anymore so you need to [release](https://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) it.

> It is a library which is a black box for me

Because the library is a c library it is unlikely (except if it is a c++ library with a c interface), that the function used to reallocate memory matches the function `make_unique` uses as default to allocate memory.

The library must document which function has to be used to allocate/free memory, and those functions have to be used by you to create the buffer that is owned by your `unuqie_ptr` and your `unqiue_ptr` needs to use the correct function (e.g. with a custom deleter) to free that buffer.

If you don't do that accordingly your application will encounter undefined behavior.

How to do that correctly can only be said if the library you use is known, and the function. Or if you provide all the necessary information on how that function reallocates memory, and which functions have to be used for memory allocation according to the library.

Under the assumption, the library does memory management a possible approach is to create a wrapper for that library:

Library code:

```
void FunctionCannotBeChanged(char** pVar);
//  allocator/free functions either provided by the library or documented by the library that those are used
char * LibraryAlloc(size_t size);
void LibraryFree(char * ptr);
```

Your wrapper:

```
namespace lib_wrapper {
    
    // deleter that is used to free the memory using the correct free function
    void library_deleter(char * ptr) {
        // you might need to add a check if the pointer is a null pointer
        LibraryFree(ptr);
    }
    
    // define an own unique ptr type that uses that custom deleter
    using unique_ptr = std::unique_ptr<char,decltype(&library_deleter)>;

    // define an own make_unqiue function that uses the correct allocator
    unique_ptr make_unique(size_t size) {
        return unique_ptr(LibraryAlloc(size),&library_deleter);
    }
    
    // create a wrapper function that:
    // - releases the pointer
    // - passes it to the library function
    // - and then passes the possibly changed ptr back to your unique ptr
    void FunctionCannotBeChanged(unique_ptr &ptr) {
        auto raw_ptr = ptr.release();
        ::FunctionCannotBeChanged(&raw_ptr);
        ptr.reset(raw_ptr);
    }
    
}

int main()
{
    auto buffer = lib_wrapper::make_unique(50);
    lib_wrapper::FunctionCannotBeChanged(buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

That shown code is for sure just a rough example, and you likely need to adapt the code to your needs.

If you want to use `void FunctionCannotBeChanged(unique_ptr &ptr)` or (what I personally prefere) `unique_ptr FunctionCannotBeChanged(unique_ptr ptr)` and then write:

```
int main()
{
    auto buffer = lib_wrapper::make_unique(50);
    buffer = lib_wrapper::FunctionCannotBeChanged(std::move(buffer));

    return 0;
}
```

Is up to you.

Creating a wrapper might be much work at the beginning, but makes your code easier to maintain, and moves the pitfalls to one central point in your wrapper code and away from the parts of your code in which you use the library.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The questions came as a result of a lack of knowledge on my side and confusion API of the lib I had to use.